# Shell.Application BrowseForFolder - how do I get full path of Folder object?

Tags: wsh

I have the following script, that I launch using `wscript`:

```
Set sh = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set rv = sh.BrowseForFolder(0, "Now browse...", 1)
WScript.Echo rv
```

How can I obtain the full path of the selected folder?

The documentation for the [`Folder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787868%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object that is returned by [`BrowseForFolder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774065%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) gives nothing appropriate.

Or maybe I should use something completely different for browsing for folders in `wscript`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rv.Self.Path`, discussed here in detail: [How Can I Show Users a Dialog Box That Only Lets Them Select Folders?](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/06/17/how-can-i-show-users-a-dialog-box-that-only-lets-them-select-folders.aspx) at *Hey, Scripting Guy! Blog*.

```
Set sh = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set rv = sh.BrowseForFolder(0, "Now browse...", 1)
If rv Is Nothing Then
    WScript.Echo "Nothing chosen"
Else
    WScript.Echo rv.Self.Path
End If
```

Comment: Scripting Guy mentions "a quirk in the Shell object", that is `Self` method. I don't mind the quirks as long as they are documented. Any idea how to find documentation of `Self`? Or an object browser that would reveal it?

Comment: Google for `technet Shell object Self method` ?

Comment: I googled for "Shell.Application vba reference" and found an msdn article *Scriptable Shell Objects*. It mentions *Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation* which can be used in Excel's VBA object browser. There is an object `Folder2`, which contains `Self`.

Comment: **Folder2.Self** property:
Contains the folder's **FolderItem** object. 
[Folder2.Self](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/folder2-self)