# Shell.BrowseForFolder in Python, how to retrieve folder path

Tags: python, activex, comtypes

I have the following code which displays the Windows folder selection window:

```
from comtypes.client import CreateObject
shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
folder = shell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select a folder", 1)
```

The Microsoft doc doesn't say anything about how to retrieve (the selected) folder path, anyway, a solution exists on the net for VB (for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31904226/shell-application-browseforfolder-how-do-i-get-full-path-of-folder-object)):

```
path = folder.Self.Path
```

This solution do not translate to comtypes, and a `help(folder)` do not show any `Self` property, it seems that `BrowseForFolder` returns a `FOLDER` type, but `Self` is a property of `FOLDER2` type, any one know why?

Comment: fwiw, it does translate to PyWin32's `win32com.client`, using that `folder.Self.Path` returns the path, so maybe it's a quirk with comtypes and needs a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

As said TessellatingHeckler above, it works with win32com:

```
import win32com.client

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("Shell.Application")
folder = shell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Now browse...", 1)
print(folder.Self.Path)
```

But if you really want to use comtypes, here is a workaround:

```
from comtypes.client import CreateObject

shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
folder = shell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Now browse...", 1)
name = folder.Title
for item in folder.ParentFolder.Items():
    if item.Name == name:
        print(item.Path)
```